# Searching in database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I need some advice how can I perform a search in the database. For example I have table in database called: `Student` the columns are: `NAME, SURNAME, UNIVERSITY, AGE, COURSE`.

When I'm filling the search form I do not specify SURNAME and UNIVERSITY and I want my search results to be every student where NAME = my specified name, AGE - my specified age and COURSE - my specified course and SURNAME and UNIVERSITY can be any.

Can someone give me some advice?

**EDIT**

Thanks for quick replay. But it seems I do not understand something or it is not working. Here is my real query:

```
SELECT UNIVERSITY, INFORMANT_NAME, AGE 
FROM informant 
WHERE UNIVERSITY='%VDU%' 
  AND INFORMANT_NAME='%Mindaugas Jonaitis%' 
  AND AGE='%21%';
```

It does not return me any result.

```
SELECT UNIVERSITY, INFORMANT_NAME, AGE 
FROM informant 
WHERE UNIVERSITY='VDU' 
  AND INFORMANT_NAME='Mindaugas Jonaitis' 
  AND AGE='21';
```

This query does, but only for specified values. I want that returned result will be all data from table where `UNIVERSITY = 'VDU'` or other values not provided or provided null or something that would be skipped.

```
SELECT UNIVERSITY, INFORMANT_NAME, AGE 
FROM informant 
WHERE UNIVERSITY='VDU' 
  AND INFORMANT_NAME='????'   
  AND AGE='????';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use wildcards you need to use `LIKE`, not `=`.

```
SELECT UNIVERSITY, INFORMANT_NAME, AGE 
FROM informant 
WHERE UNIVERSITY LIKE '%VDU%' 
  AND INFORMANT_NAME LIKE '%Mindaugas Jonaitis%' 
  AND AGE LIKE '%21%';
```

However using `like` with leading wildcards will disable any chance of using an index on that field.
If you are using MySQL with MyISAM, put an a fulltext index on the fields you want to search with wildcards and use:

```
SELECT UNIVERSITY, INFORMANT_NAME, AGE 
FROM informant 
WHERE UNIVERSITY LIKE '%VDU%' 
  AND MATCH(INFORMANT_NAME) AGAINST('Mindaugas Jonaitis')
  AND AGE LIKE '21%';
```

`Match .. against` will only work for search phrases longer than 4 chars. Also it really makes no sense to search with leading wildcards in age. I usually don't want to get all people who are `21,31,41`, I often want to get all 20-somethings though.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways of doing so. But for all of them you need to grab a `Session` from `Hibernate` . From that point on you can:

- Create a `query` object from a `named query`
- Create a `Query` object from a `sql string`
- Create a `Criteria` object

All of them then, just with either a `query.list()` or `criteria.list()`.

For more info:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html
- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 0):

A findByExample DAO method is always useful here.